# Is it possible to set a server-side cookie in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

In my Next.js app, I need to get some parameters from the URL and use them to set a server-side cookie.

But I'm not even sure if I can set a server-side cookie this way.
Is this possible at all?
If yes, any hint or suggestion would be really appreciate.

Answer (score 19):

Use **cookies-next** by the command **npm i cookies-next**

**Server Side Example**

```
import React from 'react'
import { getCookies, getCookie, setCookies, removeCookies } from 'cookies-next';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>page content</div>
  )
}

export const getServerSideProps = ({ req, res }) => {
    setCookies('test', 'value', { req, res, maxAge: 60 * 6 * 24 });
    getCookie('test', { req, res});
    getCookies({ req, res});
    removeCookies('test', { req, res});
  return { props: {}};
}

export default Home
```

**Client Side Example**

```
import { getCookies, setCookies, removeCookies } from 'cookies-next';
// we can use it anywhere
getCookies();
getCookie('key');
setCookies('key', 'value');
removeCookies('key');
```

for more information see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next

Answer (score 9):

Next applications are not working like usual server applications. Although, you can make a custom flow like using a DBaaS. Or, if you only want to restrict client access to that cookie, I think it's okay to keep them with [`httponly` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) *(you should be the one who decides that)*. In this way, you can only read that cookie at the server.

Here is an example usage with a [NextJs serverless API endpoint](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/api-routes):

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const { yourParameter } = req.query;
  res.setHeader("set-cookie", `yourParameter=${yourParameter}; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly;`)
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

You can apply the same logic to the [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) callback or other places that runs at the server.

Comment: +1 thanks. Saved my backside on this one. To this day (Next 13.1.1), this is the best way to set cookies within the API route, and not middleware (which the docs only show).

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'next/headers' cookies

[NextJS Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies)

but it needs to be mentioned:

> HTTP does not allow setting cookies after streaming starts, so you
> must use .set() in a [Server Action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations) or [Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

**Server Side Example**

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

async function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const testCookie = cookieStore.get('test')

  return { props: { testCookie }};
}
```

**middleware.ts**

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const url = new URL(request.url) // here you can destruct needed params from URL

  const cookieStore = cookies()
  cookieStore.set('key', 'value')  
}
```

Comment: you cannot set your cookies with `cookieStore.set('key', 'value') ` in middleware. It will cause "Cookies can only be modified in a Server Action or Route Handler."